# Manage Azure deadletters via powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, azure, dead-letter

Does powershell have commands to manage Topic-subscription deadletters. I want to write powershell scripts to download all deadletters or possibly iterate through deadletters and repost them based on certain criteria.